# jQuery images fade-in on ready

Tags: jquery, image

I'm currently working on a project with some very large images. To make a smooth fade-in effect when an image has been loaded, i tried to use ready() with jQuery 1.9.1, but for some reason it doesn't work and shows images before it has been loaded.

```
$("img").ready(function(){
$(this).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Thank you! I got it working with Adeneo's method: http://jsfiddle.net/hAm65/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), only the document has a ready event:

> The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document.

You can try something more like this:

```
$("img").each(function(i,el){
    var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            $(el).fadeIn("slow");
        }
        img.src = el.src;
});
```

Comment: and don't forget to hide images at startup.

Comment: @TahaPaksu - That's always a good idea, if the intention is to fade them in. I'm assuming the OP uses CSS for that, so I wont add a hide() to the code, as that usually just causes an annoying flickering.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot call `.ready` for elements other than `document` itself. use this instead

```
$("img").on('load', function(){
  $(this).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load multiple Images and need to wait for all of them to finish, try using the jQuery [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object:

```
function loadImages(src) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    };
    image.src = src;
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Use this in this way -

```
var loaders = [];
loaders.push(loadImage('1.png'));
loaders.push(loadImage('2.png'));
loaders.push(loadImage('3.png'));
$.when.apply(null, loaders).done(function() {
    // callback when everything was loaded
});
```