# Understanding Jquery promises

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have been looking into Jquery's promises through the use of `when` and I am wondering if it is capable of fullfilling my scenario or whether I need to rethink how I am doing things.

So I have a backbone.js model with a couple of listeners in like:

```
this.on('supplier:change', function(){
    $.get('/supplier_details', function(data){
        // fill in some fields here
        anotherAjaxCallInAnotherFunction();
    });
});

anotherAjaxCallInAnotherFunction: function(){
    // Another Ajax call
}
```

If I were to use `when` like so `model.set({supplier: 'ss'}).done();` would the promise be able to wait until the end of all Ajax calls?

What if I set multiple attributes that needed multiple Ajax calls within my backbone model? Would the promise encapsulate the entire setting of a model?

Comment: Not sure about the promises but async = false in your ajax calls would do the trick, no?

Comment: But i suggest you to read about how promises work https://raw.github.com/kriskowal/q/master/design/README.js in case you haven't already did this

Comment: @ant_Ti Are you sure about that? Last time I backbone was fully integrated with promises, i.e. `this.model.save().done()`

Comment: you can use `$.Deferred();` and `deferred.resolve();` when your ajax call is complete... see this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15603961/235710

Comment: @Sammaye well if so than i am wrong... sorry

Comment: @Vassilis yes but async:false consumes the browser thread, I want basically a async sync, if you know what I mean

Comment: @MohammadAdil thanks Ill need to look at that more

Comment: `model.save()` can return a `false` if validation fails, so using the promise from `save` isn't as clean as it should be.

Comment: Also, `set` returns the model instance, or `false`, not a promise.

Comment: @WiredPrairie So I am looking at this badly? Hmm, gotta figure out the best way to set attributes on promises then

Comment: There's not a straight forward "out of the box" pattern to what you want unfortunately.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Dammit I knew you were gonna say that :( thanks anyway, I'll have to restructure my code to be ugly and nasty and possibly duplicated, or I can maybe create a thin layer on top of backbone to emulate a contextual queue in the scope of setting attributes....hmm, whehter I have the time to do that though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I didn't realise until I actually tried this was that you CAN chain Ajaz calls in this way, you just need to be a bit creative with your coding.

The easiest way to chain these sort of calls is like so:

```
this.on('supplier:change', function(){
    return $.get('/supplier_details').then(function(data){
        return anotherAjaxCallInAnotherFunction();
    });
}

function anotherAjaxCallInAnotherFunction(){
    return $.ajax();
}
```

And just chaining the deferred object like this will allow you to not only make the calls async but also do it without locking the browser thread.

You can find more info here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$.when( firstAjaxCall, secondAjaxCall )
  .done( 
      function(firstResp) { console.log(firstResp); },  
      function(secondResp) { console.log(secondResp); } 
  );
```

Or you could `listenTo` a `sync` event, and when successfully returned for `firstAjaxCall`, you could call `secondAjaxCall`: [Backbone Events](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-catalog)

> "sync" (model, resp, options) — when a model (or collection) has been successfully synced with the server.

Comment: The main problem is that I can't call the when directly like that, if you look at my example I chain the two Ajax calls and I wanna know if the promise can cover the parent function call, plus I am not doing a sync here

Comment: you can nest as many calls as you like within `done()`, so why don't you try that?

Comment: Wait Wait, so taking my example instead of one from the Jquery documentation what do you mean by nesting the calls within `done()`? If I nest future Ajax calls within `Done()` am I not just nullifying the callbackless state of promises?

Comment: explain `nullifying`.  I presume your `callbackless` requirement is evident from your snippet above, oder?

Comment: Well not using lots of callbacks is the point is promises, you can catch the response later without making all that structure. If you make the full callback structure then you might as well ditch promises because they no longer do what they were designed to do, instead they are just dead weight. Yea I am hoping callback-less is possible some way here, due to the fact that I need separate self contained change functions and need them to chain while providing an element of sync without consuming the browser thread.